Azure Data Factory: How to use Exists when the source(Blob - csv) and target (SQL DB) are massive datasets (different datatypes ~370 cols, ~7M rows)
I have a scenario in Azure Data Factory where I need to compare a daily CSV file in Blob Storage with a table in an SQL Database. The goal is to copy rows from the CSV to the SQL table only if they don't already exist in the table.
Problem Details:

Data Volume: Both the CSV file and SQL table are massive, with around 370 columns and 7 million rows.
Data Types: The dataset includes various data types such as strings, doubles, and timestamps.

Approach Tried:

I followed a similar use case from this Stack Overflow post: Azure Data factory - insert a row in the azure sql database only if it doesn't exist.
I used a Data Flow with an 'Exists' transformation, leveraging a derived column with SHA2 hash for comparison.

Issues Encountered:

Data Type Mismatch: When creating the source in my Data Flow, the data types from the CSV often do not match the data types in the SQL table.
Incorrect Matching: Due to the data type mismatch, the derived columns in the Data Flow do not match correctly, resulting in all rows from the CSV being treated as non-matching.

Questions:

Data Type Handling: How can I ensure that the data types in the Data Flow match those in the SQL table to prevent mismatches?
Optimization for Large Datasets: Are there best practices or optimizations in ADF to handle such large datasets more efficiently during comparison?

Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Here is a snapshot of my dataflow:


I think if I were implementing something like this, I would use DataFlow to insert the records to a staging table in SQL, then have a SPROC that handles the actual workload.

When you import the schemas from both source and sink datasets, it is comparing the imported data types.
I have tried without importing any schema from the source and sink datasets and it got worked for the given scenario.
Clear the schema from both source and sink datasets.

This is sample source data where some rows already exists in the target table.
ID,Name,mytime,Amount,Fahrenheit,age,role,mydate
8,Laddu,2024-04-26 11:45:00,12.24,95.04,24,Pirate,02-16-00
9,MS,2024-04-27 12:00:00,24.267,10.10,26,No job,05-30-24
10,ABD,2024-04-26 11:45:00,12.24,95.04,24,Pirate,02-16-00
11,Starc,2024-04-26 11:45:00,12.24,95.04,24,Pirate,02-16-00
12,KP,2024-04-26 11:45:00,12.24,95.04,24,Pirate,2024-05-30
13,Rabada,2024-04-26 11:45:00,12.24,95.04,24,Bowler,2023-06-29
7,Rakesh,2024-04-25 10:30:00,123.451,97.16,23,Engineer,2021-12-16

In both sources of the dataflow, set the projection to empty.

The columns will not be identified by the dataflow debug. So, use byName(<column_name>) when using columns in the derived column.
Here, for the exists transformation columns, I have created extra column Id_temp in both sources like below.

Then, use these new columns in the exists transformation.

Next, use select transformation rule-based mapping to remove the extra column.

Add sink to this and execute the dataflow from the pipeline.
It will give the expected results like below.


Thank you, once again Rakesh! This is a very thorough answer and I appreciate the effort you have put into it. However, it doesnt solve my issue. I have followed the exact same process as you described in my data flow. But my main issue is with regards to the 1. data size and 2. data types.

The data types won't be imported as I haven't imported the projection. You can see I have given different data types to the SQL table, and it got copied from the csv file. The data types will be imported during the pipeline run time and they will be copied as per the target table data type. Did you tried by not importing the projection in both datasets and sources in the dataflow?

yes i tried that as well :) the hash value doesnt seem to match still.

The byName() function should be wrapped in any of the data type like toString() or toInt(). Then, apply the hash function on it.

Okay. i see what you did. Actually, i was trying something different. i basically did a deep dive of the 369 columns to identify what were critical for the sanity of the data set. I have narrowed down to 5 of them, made sure these 5 columns data types matched in both the source and target source and manually entered these 5 columns in the hash function. now the data flow seems to work as expected  :) I suppose your solution seems to do something similar. I will accept this as the answer. Thank you once again Rakesh!

Here’s a step-by-step summary of my approach:

Identify Unique Columns: Examine your data to find columns or a set of columns that uniquely identify each row. For my dataset, two specific columns provided a unique combination.
Create Derived Column and use these unique columns and generate a SHA2 hash.
Apply the 'Exists' transformation using the derived hash column to compare the source CSV rows with the SQL table rows.

I hope this helps others facing a similar problem. Feel free to ask if you need more details on the implementation.

Great to know, that it benefitted you. Another workaround can be copying all the data from csv to a temp SQL table using copy activity first. The temp table should have same data types as the original table. Here, also don't import the mapping in copy activity, it will explicitly copy the data to temp SQL table. Then, use your dataflow with the temp table as source and target table as sink. Here, as all source and target data types are same, It won't give this problem.

how can i possibly go through the 370 columns and add them one by one using byName()? Is there any other alternative?

There is no need to go through all columns in the dataflow. Whatever the columns that you require for the exits condition, use toString(byName('<column_name>')) for those and remove them using select after the exists. As you didn't imported the projection, it will take all the columns as usual when you debug the dataflow from the pipeline.

Unfortunately, i need to use all the columns in my exists. Earlier i tried using just the unique columns in the exists activity. However, my data could have duplicate rows (on unique columns) based on the updates to the values of some of the columns, and we never know which columns were changed or updated in the backend processes. .

I tried your suggestion of not importing the projection. Although, exists seem to work with this, i run into a different problem. When i finally want to upsert on the sink, i cannot use the key columns and it throws an error which basically says it cannot find the key column.

I did try sha2(256, toString(columns())) function to get the derived column from both sources, but the derived columns do not seem to match and i alwasy end up with the entire source as unmatched/new data, which isnt true in my case.

You need to use byName() in the upsert dynamic expression as well. I haven't tried it yet though but it should work.
